# Proof that a first integral is not a constant function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-topology, differential-equations

Let $U$ be an (open) set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. And we are given a set of  $m$ basis functions
$$B=\{\psi_i(x): U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\mid i=1,\ldots,m \}$$
such that all of them are differentiable and non-constant. We define a DS by
$$\dot{x}(t)=F(x(t))$$
and set $\Phi: U \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow U, \quad (x_0, t) \mapsto \Phi(x_0,t)$ as the flow of the DS.

Now we look at a function which is a linear combination in the basis functions ($\theta \in \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$)
$$\Lambda: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \ x \mapsto \sum_{i=0}^m \theta_i \psi_i(x)$$
where $V \subseteq U$ is some open possibly smaller subset of $U$.

Now we know (by some different result) that for each point/ inital condition $x_0=x(0)$ and the according trajectory $x(t)$ there is a **non-zero** vector $\theta(x_0) \in \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ (with components $\theta_i(x_0), \quad i=0,...,m$) such that

$$ \Lambda(x_0)=\sum_{i=0}^m \theta_i(x_0) \psi_i(\Phi(x_0,t))=0$$

So, $\Lambda$ is a function which maps $V$ to zero. The special porperty is that along a trajectory $\theta_i(x_0) \ \forall i $ is constant, hence its value is defined by the value at the initial condition. But for different trajectories/initial conditions $x_0' \neq x_0$ the value of $\theta_i(x'_0) \neq \theta_i(x_0)$ is allowed to be different from $\theta(x_0)$. (We actually want to prove that this has to be the case)

Now we set the function
$$\Lambda'(x(t))=\sum_{i=1}^m \theta_i(x_0) \psi_i(\Phi(x_0,t))=- \theta_0(x_0)$$
for which we want to prove that it is a local (i.e. on $V$) 1. Integral of $F$. I know that the Lie derivative $L_F(\Lambda)=0$ is zero, which is the first thing I need to prove. But I am struggling to prove that the function is not locally constant.

---

**My question is the following:** Can we prove that $\Lambda' $ is not locally constant? More formally, $$\exists x_0,x_0' \in V: \quad \Lambda'(x_0)=-\theta_0(x_0) \neq -\theta_0(x_0')=\Lambda'(x_0')$$
I.e. are there two initial conditions $x_0 \neq x_0'$ for which the the first (or zeroth depending on the convention) entry of the $\theta$-vector needs to be different $\theta_0(x_0) \neq \theta_0(x_0')$

---

I think this has to be true, since for two different inital conditions $\Phi(x_0^1,t) \neq \Phi(x_0^2,t) \ \forall t$. And since all functions are non-constant the parameters can't be the same but I am lacking a formal proof. Especially how I can conclude from the fact that the parameters are not the same that the value of the function is not the same. (If it helps , the vector field $F$ itself is a linear combination of the basis functions $\psi_i$ in each dimension.)

Comment: Cross posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4760367/proof-that-a-first-integral-is-not-a-constant-function

Comment: What is a basis function?

Comment: In the definition of $\Lambda$, are we saying that for each point $x$, we write that point as $x=x(t)$ for a point $x_0:=\Phi(x,-t)$? The notation is not clear to me. It looks like you are defining $\Lambda$ in terms of a particular value of $t$. Is that right?

Comment: @BenMcKay A basis function is just a differentiable function of the form I described above. I called it basis function because we expand the other functions in terms of these functions. $\Lambda(x(t))$ is defined for all t. But on a given trajectory $x(t)$ it has a constant value due to the fact that the Lie deriavtive is zero.

Comment: There are several things, I don't understand. The flow $\Phi(x,t)$ has values in $M$ (I assume that the vector field $F$ is good enough to have $\Phi:M\times\mathbb R\to M$), hence in order to $\psi_i(\Phi(x_0,t))$ make sense, you would need $M\subseteq \mathbb R^n$. There are several $\theta$: Is $\theta(x_0)\in \mathbb R^{m+1}\setminus\{0\}$ with components $\theta_i(x_0)$? What is $x(t)$ in the definition of $\Lambda$? If it is a solution of the equation $\dot{x}(t)=F(x(t))$, what is the initial condition? Finally, doesn't $\psi_1=-\psi_2$, $\theta_1(x_0)=\theta_2(x_0)=1$ yield $\Lambda=0$?

Comment: I still don't follow the notation. When you write $\Lambda(x(t))=\dots$, do you mean that there is a function $\Lambda$, defined on $M$, or on $U$, with the property that, for any point $x_0\in U$ and time $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $\Lambda(x(t))$ is equal to the given expression? Also, what is $\theta_0$ defined to be? We suppose that there is a point $\theta(x_0)\in\mathbb{R}^m$, but its components are $\theta_i(x_0)$, $i=1,2,\dots,m$.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth I edited the question to hopefully address all the unclear points. I redefined $U$ to just be an open set on $\mathbb{R}^n$ .

Comment: @BenMcKay I edited the question and redefined $\Lambda$

Comment: I think you are using $\theta$ to mean two different things: the components of the expression of $\Lambda$ are called $\theta_i$, while the nonzero vector $\theta(x_0)$ has components with the same names.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that a basis function means precisely a real valued function on $U$ which is differentiable and nonconstant?

Comment: You seem to have written that $\Lambda$ is a function that maps an open set $V$ to zero. But you also write that $\Lambda$ is only defined on $V$. So $\Lambda=0$ is constant.

Comment: @BenMcKay Sorry, I want to proof that $\Lambda '$ is non constant. Which maps to $\theta_{0}(x_0)$. Not $\Theta$.

Comment: @BenMcKay About the basis functions you are right. Yeah $\theta_i(x_0)$ are the components of $\theta(x_0)$. I just introduced $\theta$ in the beginning to clarify that $\Lambda$ is a linear comnination in the basis functions.